# Could a Time Lord/Lady recognise other Time Lord/Lady independent from their regenerations?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

Could a Time Lord/Lady recognise other Time Lord/Lady independent from their regenerations? Like when The Doctor “recognise” the [Time Lady](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Woman_%28The_End_of_Time%29) in "The end of time" or when The Doctor recognise The Master in "Utopia"?

The Master also avoided to see the Doctor before the Doctor timeline reaches the point where the Master already have stolen the TARDIS.

Comment: The Time Lady was somebody he definitely knew because he was there at the time war.  Timelords always know who each other are because of their regenerations... For example when The Master returned during the End of Time... The Doctor had already seen that face so he knew it was The Master.

Comment: Wasn't there an episode where they traveled to the end of humanity and the Master was there, but had lost his memory, i.e. he was locked in that watch thing? The Doctor didn't recognise the Master IIRC.

Comment: @user1129682 I think it was because The Master were not a time lord at the time. (Remember that they lose the Time lord essence/wibbly-wobbly-stuff when they use that "clock". They doesn't only lose the memory.

Comment: @user1129682 Well yeah, but that guy looked like [Emperor Clau-Clau-Claudius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Claudius_%28TV_series%29).

Comment: Could the person who downvote this question, explain why you did it? so it could be fixed. [Should we downvote duplicates?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62819/should-we-downvote-duplicates) - ["In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/159220)